# Foreign key for a combination of columns

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relations` (
  `id1` INT NOT NULL,
  `id2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id1`, `id2` ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( `id1`, `id2` ) REFERENCES `a` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
  `id1` INT NOT NULL,
  `id2` INT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id1`, ... )
);
```

The `id1` and `id2` in the `relations` table AND in the `b` table refer to a row in table `a`. Now I would like to implement the following:
Every row in `b` needs to have a row in `relations` consisting of the two `id`s in `b`. `id1` in `b` can be either `id1` or `id2` in `relations` and `id2` in `b` can be either `id2` or `id1` in `relations`. If the relation between two `id`s is deleted from the `relations` table, I want to delete any row with those two `id`s in the `b` table. Is it possible to achieve this with FOREIGN KEYs?

Answer (score 2):

Order matters in foreign key constraints, so no, you cannot achieve that with foreign key constraints.

But you could rule that there has to be an order in `relations`, e.g. `id1 < id2` or (`id1 <= id2`), and in `b`. In newer MySQL versions (MySQL 8.0.16 and up) you could use a check constraint for that. In older ones you'd need triggers. Then the tuples are comparable and you can use a foreign key constraint.

Make sure there's a unique index on the tuple in the referenced table.

And as a side note: The foreign key's syntax in your `CREATE` statement of `relations` is wrong. You'd need to make one constraint for each column `id1` and `id2`. You cannot do that in one. (But that mistake probably only happened here and isn't in the actual code.)